# Trying to get all combinations without duplicated numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates, combinations, python-itertools

I am trying to make a 5 number combination but without repeating the same number. My numbers are from 1 to 45 and I am trying to see the multiple combinations that they can have.

So far I have been able to print and save the combinations. But from the data I can see that there are many duplicates values.

For example: (34,34,34,35,37)

What I want to do is basically have each number not repeat itself like if its 34 then it cant come again into the combination set of 5

`

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
import sys

#get all combinations of 1, 2, nad length 10

c= combinations_with_replacement([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45], 5)

print(sys.getsizeof(c))

print(c)

res = str(''.join(map(str,c)))

file= open("sample.txt","w")

file.write(res)

file.close()
print(res)
```

`

Comment: Well, you used combinations_**with_replacement**, so of course you get duplicates...

Comment: As a side note, `sys.getsizeof(c)` won't give you the `len`gth of the list...

Answer (score 0):

**The following code will print out all the combinations, one per line.**

```py
import itertools

numbers = range(1, 46)  # Set of numbers to choose from (1 to 45)
combinations = itertools.combinations(numbers, 5)  # Generate all combinations of 5 numbers

for combination in combinations:
  print(combination)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply use the following, you won't have combinatoins with repeated elements:

```
import itertools
my_list = range(45)
my_iters = list(itertools.combinations(my_list, 5))
```

You can check this is the case simply by comparing the length of each elemnt of my_iters with the length of the subsequent set:

```
my_iters_unique = [x for x in my_iters  if len(set(x)) == len(x)]
```

And you will see the length of *my_iters_unique*  and *my_iters* are the same.